# Wildcards SQL joining similar tables and printing combined results

Tags: mysql, wildcard

How can I query (mysql) many similar tables, that capture data for each day of the month, let's say, these tables are called: orders_20200401, orders_20200402, .... orders_20200430
and I want to count the total number of orders for the full month

Comment: The question is: why would you do that? It would be a lot simpler to have one table for your data and add a date column. This way you could just group the values by dates.

Comment: If you have to stick with your solution of multiple tables you would have to read the tablenames from the information schema, parse those dates and somehow join them generically.

Comment: Fix your broken schema

Comment: Thanks for the response! Agreed I would have 1 table if I created something like this.
This is an exercise I was given, and I'd love to figure out how to solve it.
Read online you can use regex, but I'm new to this, so not sure how